# Wrong operating system gets displayed online

Tags: browser, system-information

When I visit a page like https://www.whatismyip.com it displays 
the following:

*Browser Info
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0*

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 cinnamon 64-bit wih Firefox 46.0

Linux-Kernel: 3.13.0-37-generic

What could be next steps to investigate this behavior?

Comment: see also: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: Thank you. Found also this related article about fingerprinting. [https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/12/01/browser-fingerprints-the-invisible-cookies-you-cant-delete/] I was not aware of this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites get your browser type and OS information from the user agent string presented by your browser. In your case, start `firefox`. On the URL box, type `about:config` and search for `useragent`. You will see few entries. One of those is responsible for presenting your OS as a windows OS.